# Cocoa IOSurfaces and synchronization with background task pulling frames via Quicktime

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ipc, quicktime

I've a question regarding IOSurface on Cocoa.
After an extensive research required to switch my OPENGL realtime application to 64 bit, I've taken the only path to support Quicktime playback spawning a background thread that pulls the frames installing a frame-ready callback and then with QTVisualContextCopyImageForTime , and pass the IOSurfaceRef through RPC to the parent process.

Everything works fine but there's one main issue. In my 32 bit application I was able to serialize any call to the GL subsystem by rendering a frame, pull the QT frames for the next pass and then wait for the next V-sync. This produced a very smooth and stable result.

Using the IOSurface technique gives me no way to synchronize when my app draws a frame and when the background process pulls the IOSurface from the quicktime movie. The result is that, on a random basis, I experience performances SPYKES. Indeed using the OPENGL driver monitor raises the CPU WAIT cycles up to 10% in my 64 bit app, while I have 0% CPU Wait graph under 32 bit.

Anyone here used IOSurface in a real world application and faced issues like this one ? I've though about an interprocess mutex/lock , but considering I need to lock/unlock about 120 times x second, I was not able to find a valid solution, it doesn't seems that darwin has something like the NAMED SIGNALS available in Win32...

Any suggestion, or I should take a totally different approach to the problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Did you find another approach? I too am using CVDisplaylink to drive an OpenGL view displaying quicktime images on a quad. I know that QTVisualContextRef does not work on 64-bt builds, and I was looking t IOSurfaces myself as a solution.

Comment: yes use IOSurfaces in the spawned process, but just use the same IOSurface, you can bind it directly to an OGL Texture and have in changed without any handshaking between the processes.

Comment: Would you have any code examples? What I am doing now (I am revisiting this project after a year plus) is generating a mach_port that from an  IOSurface. I send that mach_port integer to another process and attempt to create an IOSurfaceRef from that mach port. If I pass an IOSurfaceID, I can instantiate the IOSurface correctly, however if I pass a mach_port_t, I can not. From what you mentioned, you create one IOSurfaceRef and simply bind it to your texture once. Your IOSurfaceRef is updated behind your back. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes , as long as you bake an IOSurface to a texture, you can simply pass the ID to another process and have the texture updates automatically, this is what apple uses in the multi-gpu rendering example....